# DataAnnotation showing tooltip instead of highlighting the field

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I'm having a problem with the `[EmailAddress]` DataAnnotation in ASP.NET MVC 4. My objective is only to highlight the field with a basic design when it doesn't pass on the validation, like as below.

[Link 1](http://s27.postimg.org/6qazbcq4z/error1.png) (my rep. doesn't allow to post images)

In the field above, i'm using a `[RegularExpression]` and a `[Required]`, and no problems until here.

But when i apply the `[EmailAddress]` one, this happens:

[Link 2](http://s30.postimg.org/wxsaoqz4x/error2.png)

How can I get rid of this tooltip and only have the highlight?

My code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Campo obrigatório.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\(\d{2}\)\d{4,5}-\d{4}", ErrorMessage="Insira um telefone válido.")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
[EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

**UPDATE 1**:

Now I really don't know if the problem is with `[EmailAddress]`. I've just made another test:

1 - If I just put something in the left of the @, and submit the form, it stays with the tooltip, as on Link 2

2 - If I put, for example: foo@foo and then submit the form, now it is displayed correctly, only highlighting the field (and with a custom ErrorMessage, if I want to), as on Link 1.

**UPDATE 2. NOTE: I'm using some custom fields. The `TextBoxCNPJFor()` works OK. The standard one `EditorFor(model => model.Email)` is the one who cause the problem**:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxCNPJFor(model => model.CNPJ)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CNPJ)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm just guessing here but does whatever JavaScript validation framework Microsoft have bundled with MVC treat errors with messages differently to just errors? What happens if you supply a custom error message in your `[EmailAddress]` attribute, e.g. `[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Not a valid email address.")]`?

Comment: Hey @Sean, i've updated my question with relevant comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

My script bundles wasn't being loaded correctly. I put it on the right order and now it's working OK. Thanks for everyone who helped me.